# Firestore v9 onSnapshot handling the listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with one part of Firestore. I’m trying to separate all of my data queries in a separate files, so from the front end I don’t need to repeat myself with the queries. So in the separate files I’m creating functions that take parameters and return the data. All good so far. When I use getDoc(doc(db, 'Projects', 'id) it work perfectly fine, it returns the section:

```
const getSection = async (projectID, sectionID) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, `Projects/${projectID}/Sections`, `s${sectionID}`)
    const section = await getDoc(docRef)

    return section.data();
}
```

But my project requires to use onSnapshot to listen to changes in the database and change the frontend appropriately. Problem is I don’t seem to be able to get a handle on the data coming from the onSnapshot listener. I can log the data, but I can’t store it in a variable that I can return. Example:

```
const getSection = async (projectID, sectionID) => {
    const docRef = doc(db, `Projects/${projectID}/Sections`, `s${sectionID}`)
    
    let section = {}
    const unsub = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());   // This log the exact data that I want

        section = doc.data();
    })
    console.log(section)    // This return undefined

    return section;         // So this returns absolutely nothing
}
```

**** EDIT ****

I'm able to do it when I use onSnapshot to access collections:

```
    const getAllSections = async (sectionID, projectID) => {
        let sections = [];
        const sectionCollectionRef = collection(db, `Projects/${projectID}/Sections`)

        onSnapshot(sectionCollectionRef, (snap) => {
            snap.forEach((section) => {
                sections.push(section.data())
            })
        })
        console.log(sections) // This works perfectly and every time something changes it refreshes the frontend
    
    return sections;
}
```

So this is what I'm trying to do with getting info from a document, instead of a collection

Comment: The point of `onSnapshot` is to get multiple values, spread over time. What are you wanting to return, just the first value?

Comment: I want to save/update the value each time the database updates, in order to update the frontend.

Comment: @VeniM Are you using a front end framework or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using React

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're using react, this should be done in a useEffect, and you should set state each time the new data arrives.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [section, setSection] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = doc(db, `Projects/${projectID}/Sections`, `s${sectionID}`)
    
    const unsub = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      setSection(doc.data();
    })
    return unsub
  }, [sectionId]);

  // ... rest of the component which uses `section`
}
```

Comment: That does work, but I'm trying to separate these database queries in a separate file, in order to avoid writing the same code all over in every component that needs it. It's hard to maintain that way, and if an update comes from firestore that breaks the code I will need to go into every component and individually fix it.